# ASP.NET, Kendo UI, CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, kendo-grid

SOLUTION AT THE BOTTOM OF POST

I've been struggling to view my data through a Kendo.UI grid for few days,
guess I fail to understand some basic concept on how to do it since I'm new to aspnet and all this kind of stuff.

Index.cshtml :

```
 @using Kendo.Mvc.UI
 @using System.Linq;


    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CardsDemo.Models.CardsViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
    columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Card ID").Width(130);
    columns.Bound(p => p.State).Title("State").Width(130);
    columns.Bound(p => p.ExpirationDate).Title("Expiration Date").Width(130);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
.Filterable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .ServerOperation(false)  
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetCards", "Home"))   
 ).Render()
)
```

HomeController.cs :

```
...
    [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetCards([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            var cards = repository.GetAll();
            var cardsvm = new CardsViewModel(cards);
            return Json(cardsvm.GetCards.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
...
```

Project builds without errors, however the webpage says :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

    Compilation Error

    Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

    Compiler Error Message: CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

    Source Error:


    Line 8:      .Columns(columns =>
    Line 9:      {
    Line 10:         columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Title("Card ID").Width(130);
    Line 11:         columns.Bound(p => p.State).Title("State").Width(130);
    Line 12:         columns.Bound(p => p.ExpirationDate).Title("Expiration Date").Width(130);

    Source File: c:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CardsDemo\Views\Home\Index.cshtml    Line: 10
```

EDIT : As suggested, I tried putting breakpoints and figured that program crashes right after Index ends (included homeControllers Index action code);

EDIT2 : @clement the Kendo() in layout.cshtml is underlined in red, saying

```
Error   3   'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'Kendo' and no extension method 'Kendo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CardsDemo\Views\Home\Index.cshtml 3   12  CardsDemo
```

Tho I believe it is a Visual Studio related bug, which is also connected to IntelliSense not working properly in cshtml files.
My colleagues say they also have this in their projects, but they just ignore it, and it works.

SOLUTION : So it works if you change Index.cshtml to :

```
@model ICollection<CardsDemo.Models.CardViewModel>

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
        columns.Bound(p => p.State);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ExpirationDate);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetCards", "Home"))
                )
    )
```

Comment: You may want to swap System.Linq to System.Data.Entity

Comment: I am using NHibernate in this project

Answer (score 0):

it looks like that you use Linq without embedding *System.Linq*  to the view.

EDIT: 
Can you put breakpoint into view/controller and be sure that the "Name" property that you send to view is a string?

Comment: '@using System.Linq;' doesn't change anything, whether I have it or not :(

Comment: @mattytommo sorry I didn't saw this

Comment: I have updated the question(see EDIT at the end of question)
thank you for your willingness to help

Comment: 'Name' is an integer, tried to change it to string, didn't help.

Comment: always the same error? no exception? could you make a Application_Error in global asax to catch exception if there is one?

Comment: I've added the example code from msdn for application_error in global asax. It returned "Global Page Error

c:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CardsDemo\Views\Home\Index.cshtml(7): error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: @evictednoise: there is no error, no warkings on the view when you compile the code?

Comment: ... It probably doesn't work but...try to replace the KendoUI by <p>Hello</p> on the view and launch the app (we never know)

Comment: if I replace the whole grid code with just <p>Hello</p> it compiles, runs and displays the expected output 'Hello' .

Comment: I've added EDIT2 regarding the error in view. It does disappear after I rebuild, and comes up when I edit something

Comment: @evictednoise AHAH! did you made any changes into the web?config in order to add <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI" /> under <napespaces> ?

Comment: you added and you get issue or you've added and it works? this line is used to let ASP.NET MVC know of the Kendo.Mvc.UI namespace where the server-side wrappers are. You also have to add Kendo.Mvc.dll on the references of the client

Comment: can you post a model for this. with its properties